# Determine if a triangle is right angled with only coordinates

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

What is the easiest way to determine that, given 3 coords, they DON'T form a right angled triangle?

EG, (0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0) - forms a right angled triangle

(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0.5, 0) - does not form a right angled triangle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 points always form a triangle.

For a triangle with side lengths $a$, $b$, $c$, the Pythagorean theorem states that if *and only if* $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ then the triangle is a right triangle.

---

If $a$ is the distance between points $p$ and $q$, with $p = \begin{bmatrix} p_1 \\ p_2 \\ p_3 \end{bmatrix}$, and $q = \begin{bmatrix} q_1 \\ q_2 \\ q_3 \end{bmatrix}$,

then $$a = |P - Q| = \sqrt{(p_1 - q_1)^2 + (p_2 - q_2)^2 + (p_3 - q_3)^2}$$

so

$$a^2 = (p_1 - q_1)^2 + (p_2 - q_2)^2 + (p_3 - q_3)^2$$

Comment: so is that for any sides, or does c have to be the hypotenuse

Comment: $c$ has to be the longest for the relation to hold at all.

Comment: what about when the point are laying on the same line? This test will lead to a false positive

Comment: calculating the dot product will cover this case as well

Answer (score 1):

Draw it and test the angle that seems likely taking the dot product of the two vectors corresponding to the sides of that vertex. You can test all three if you don't want to draw.

---

Alternatively calculate the side lengths, if $c$ is the largest and $c^2=a^2+b^2$  it is a right triangle, otherwise it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

For this, I believe it is best to calculate the length of every side before using Pythagoras theorem, hope this helps!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/916757)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: This attempts to answer the question. It is clearly not suited as a comment as it does neither of the things that comments are for.